# Pester Mock imported module

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

I'm using version pester version 5.1.0

I've created a simple test.psm1

```
function testScript { write-host 'hello' }
```

I've create a pester file let's call it test-tests.ps1

```
Describe "test" {
    Context "test call" {
           Import-Module .\test.psm1
           Mock -ModuleName 'test' testScript { write-host 'hello3' } 
           testScript
    }
}
```

When I run this it comes back with 'hello'.
For the life of me I cannot see why Pester will not use the Mock version of testScript and return 'hello3'.  Anyone see where I'm going wrong with pester?

Answer (score 2):

The `-ModuleName` parameter tells `Mock` where to *inject* the mock, not where to find the function definition.

What you're currently doing is saying that any calls to `testScript` from *inside* your `test.psm1` module should be intercepted and replaced with the mock, but any calls from *outside* the module (e.g. in your `test-tests.ps1`) still call the original `testScript`.

From https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/modules:

> Notice that in this example test script, all calls to Mock and Should -Invoke have had the -ModuleName MyModule parameter added. This tells Pester to inject the mock into the module's scope, which causes any calls to those commands from inside the module to execute the mock instead.

The simple fix is to remove the `-ModuleName test` parameter.

To make it a bit clearer, try adding a second function into your module:

**test.psm1**

```
function testScript
{
    write-host 'hello'
}

function testAnother
{
    testScript
}
```

and update your test suite to be this:

**test-tests.ps1**

```
Describe "test" {
    Context "test call" {
           Import-Module .\test.psm1
           Mock -ModuleName 'test' testScript { write-host 'hello3' } 
           testScript
           testAnother
    }
}
```

If you try with and without `-ModuleName 'test'` you'll see the output is either

```
hello3
hello
```

or

```
hello
hello3
```

depending on where the mock is being injected (i.e. inside the module, or inside the test suite).